# Can you rename the App_Code folder?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I realize this would violate convention, but I'm curious to know if you can do this through configuration.

**Edit:  I understand why I wouldn't want to do this.  BUT, I do want to understand the internals of this time of project.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot rename this folder and have it actually contain executable code.  The web project system is hard coded to look for code in this folder and will not consider any other folder for raw code.

Answer (score 1):

Reflector tells me that **System.Web.HttpRuntime** contains...

```
internal const string CodeDirectoryName = "App_Code";
```

So the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is posible, but why do you need to change it?

Comment: I don't need to change it, but I'm wondering how the App_Code folder works behind the scenes.  Is it simply a default that you could override?

Answer (score 0):

Google "Convention over Configuration"

Comment: Convention over configuration (also known as coding by convention) is a software design paradigm which seeks to decrease the number of decisions that developers need to make, gaining simplicity, but not necessarily losing flexibility. (via Wikipedia)